# Replace inner text of sibling of node having some inner text using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am having an xml and I am trying to find a node having inner text as `123` then find its following or preciding sibling `duration` and then replacing its value.

**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<classes>
<class>
  <id>123</id>
  <duration>100</duration>
  <price>price</price>
</class>
<class>
  <id>234</id>
  <duration>10</duration>
  <price>100</price>
</class>
<class>
  <id>123</id>
  <duration>120</duration>
  <price>price</price>
</class>
</classes>
```

**XSLT**:

```
<xsl:template match="id[text()='123']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::duration) or count(preceding-sibling::duration)">
            <xsl:text>abc</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<classes>
<class>
  <id>123</id>
  <duration>newValue</duration>
  <price>price</price>
</class>
<class>
  <id>234</id>
  <duration>10</duration>
  <price>100</price>
</class>
<class>
  <id>123</id>
  <duration>newValue</duration>
  <price>price</price>
</class>
</classes>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="class[id='123']/duration">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>abc</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or:

```
<xsl:template match="duration[../id='123']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>abc</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

instead of:

```
<xsl:template match="id[text()='123']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::duration) or count(preceding-sibling::duration)">
            <xsl:text>abc</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: can we add a attribute to `class` of matched node?

Comment: If you match the `class` node itself, e.g. as  `match="class[id='123']"` then you can.

Comment: @Beginner Compare: http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rMJ/3 -- P.S.  If you have another question, please post it as another question.

Answer (score 1):

**Match `duration` rather than `id`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="duration[   preceding-sibling::id = '123' 
                                or following-sibling::id = '123']">
    <xsl:copy>newValue</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Then your input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<classes>
  <class>
    <id>123</id>
    <duration>100</duration>
    <price>price</price>
  </class>
  <class>
    <id>234</id>
    <duration>10</duration>
    <price>100</price>
  </class>
  <class>
    <id>123</id>
    <duration>120</duration>
    <price>price</price>
  </class>
</classes>
```

**Will transform to the output you requested:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classes>
  <class>
      <id>123</id>
      <duration>newValue</duration>
      <price>price</price>
  </class>
  <class>
      <id>234</id>
      <duration>10</duration>
      <price>100</price>
  </class>
  <class>
      <id>123</id>
      <duration>newValue</duration>
      <price>price</price>
  </class>
</classes>
```